# Workflow to check for substring in field in each item of a List

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, loop

How can I build a workflow to incrementally check each item of a List for a certain substring? I have a list of over 900 items and need to check for a certain substring within a Multiple Lines of Text field, then if it's found, run a different workflow. After that other workflow has completed, then I'd like to run the original workflow again, until every item has been checked.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in other workflow, if certain substring is found?

Comment: @FalakMahmood, the other workflow finds the substring and repaces it with a null value.

Comment: You can do this with PowerShell, which later can be scheduled as task? Fast and convenient. However, you do need access to server to schedule the task